Remove NTFS Delete from Domain users but retain for Administrator Azure file share
We have an Azure file share added to via ADDS (AD computer object representing the Azure share). We configured the Azure share to assign Contribute access to all users.
We now wish to limit users from Deleting any file/folder created using NTFS permissions, but Domain Admins should still be able to delete.
One way is to create a separate AD group that contains all users, excluding admins, and remove delete permission to that group, but that means we have to maintain this group when users come and go. What would be the best method to allow this?

So explicitly deny the permission on the user group you wish to remove the ability to delete files and explicitly allow the permissions for then user group you want to give it to. So what’s your question? Users and Administrators are the user groups.

If I Deny on the users group, this includes Administrators, so that does not give desired result, since Deny takes precedence over Allow.

Have you tried?

This may have been a very basic question for some, but I wanted to know if I was missing something. I wanted to avoid creating and managing another AD group to achieve my goal, in this case, creating the group was unavoidable.
Once the decision to make another group was made, the solution is simple; add everyone to the AD group excluding Administrators. Then, add this group and Deny "delete" NTFS permission and let it inherit to subfolders and files.
You must do this using PowerShell, since you cannot search AD groups through Security tab in Properties (it will search the storage account computer AD object, so it will not find the created AD group).
This is the script I used to add the group and Deny permission:
#Define variables
$aclPath = "\\Path\to\share"

#Get needed ACL from path/file
$acl = Get-ACL -Path $aclPath

#Show current state of ACL
Write-Host "===================="
Write-Host "Current ACL"
Write-Host "===================="
$acl | Format-List

#Do NOT Remove current permissions and inherited permissions
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($false,$false)

#Configure and Set new Access Rule
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain\ADGroup", "delete", "containerInherit,objectInherit", "inheritOnly", "deny")
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-ACL $aclPath

#Show new state of ACL
Write-Host "===================="
Write-Host "New ACL"
Write-Host "===================="
$acl | Format-List

Read-Host -Prompt "Press any key to close..."

